# Python Pandas speed up comparison of columns with scalar

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm having some performance issues with Pandas Dataframe operations.

What I need to do are groupby aggregations and formulas on the rows which match each row which is being evaluated. So basically I need to loop over the Dataframe

I thought about adding boolean columns to a Dataframe where the row value matches a variable.

I already casted the strings to ints since this saves memory and probably speeds things up.

My code is this:

```
columns = ['a','b','c']
for i in columns:
    labels,unique = pd.factorize(df1[i])
    df1[i] = labels
    df1[i+"_match"] = np.zeros(len(df1.index),bool)

for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    for col in columns:
        df1[col + '_match'] = df1[col] == row[col]

result = some_groupby_stuff(i,row,df1)
```

I timed it and the bottleneck is in:

```
 df1[col + '_match'] = df1[col] == row[col]
```

and when not assinging it to the dataframe but just a variable the time halves:

```
 d = df1[col] == row[col] # time halves
```

How can I do this better/faster? (on a 10K by 7 dataframe it already takes 12 seconds.)

I don't see a way to eliminate the loop over all rows of the dataframe, however I was thinking maybe another solution could be to make a 3-dimensional matrix (n_rows,n_rows,n_cols) where on place i,j,z is 1 if in df1 row i and row j both are true for column z.
But I don't know if Pandas has such an option (implemented in C else I don't think it would be faster) and I'm not sure if this (sparse) matrix would take up to much memory. 
Cython could an option but for easy adjustments to the code I would prefer to stay with Pandas/Numpy.

EDIT:

Okay I changed the code up a bit. Instead of looping while generating the columns it's easier/faster to just add all dummy columns.
This is the total code:
generating the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator, math,string,random

#creating random data

#num of rows of data to create
n=500

t = np.array([round(math.exp((np.random.random_sample()*5)-1)*1.5,3) for i in np.arange(n)])
t[t<1] = 0
s = np.array([round(math.exp((np.random.random_sample()*2)-1),3) for i in np.arange(n)])
s[s<0.8] = 0

part = min(int((n**.25))*2,26)

a = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase[:part] + string.ascii_uppercase[:part],k=2)) for i in np.arange(n)])
a[list(np.random.choice(n,int(n/15)))] = ''
b = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/2)] + string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/2)],k=2)) for i in np.arange(n)])
b[list(np.random.choice(n,int(n/10)))] = ''
c = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/3)] + string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/3)],k=2)) for i in np.arange(n)])
c[list(np.random.choice(n,int(n/8)))] = ''
d = np.array([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/4)] + string.ascii_uppercase[:int(part/4)],k=2)) for i in np.arange(n)])
d[list(np.random.choice(n,int(n/5)))] = ''

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([t,s,a,b,c,d]).transpose(), columns=['T','S','A','B','C','D'])

df['T'] = pd.to_numeric(df['T'])
df['S'] = pd.to_numeric(df['S'])

#minimum T
threshold=100

#order of importance of columns
w = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}

for i in w.keys():    
    temp = pd.get_dummies(df[i], dummy_na=False, prefix=i,drop_first=False,sparse=False)
    df = df.join(temp)

df['sum_avg'] = np.zeros(len(df.index))

#time till here is negligible
```

The actual function to speed up:

```
def function_to_speed_up(df2,thresholdCondition,w):
    """
        loop over rows, and keep adding data from other groups of rows
        which are less similar until the threshold is reached.
    """
    for i,row in df2.iterrows():

        stats = row[['T','S']]
        w_temp = w.copy()

        while (stats['T'] < threshold) & any(w_temp):
            #because prefix at dummy creation make list of current columns to use
            cols = [str(x) + '_' + str(y) for x, y in dict(row[w_temp.keys()]).items()]
            # if all columns in this selection are 1/True the row belongs to the current "row/group" 
            temp = df2.loc[df2.loc[:, cols].prod(axis=1) > 0, ['T', 'S']].sum()
            #add row values to total
            stats['T'] = stats['T'] + temp['T'] - row['T']
            stats['S'] = stats['S'] + temp['S'] - row['S']

            # make group broader if threshold not reached yet.
            del w_temp[min(w_temp.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]]

        df2['sum_avg'].iloc[i] = stats['S']/stats['T']
    return df2
```

running the code with prun:

```
 %prun awnser = function_to_speed_up(df,threshold,w)
```

returns:

```
             9665853 function calls (9526106 primitive calls) in 39.552 seconds

       Ordered by: internal time

       ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
          500   31.663    0.063   31.663    0.063 {built-in method gc.collect}
      1542640    0.430    0.000    0.877    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
       983182    0.316    0.000    0.352    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
    112630/110028    0.213    0.000    0.285    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
        19914    0.200    0.000    0.586    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.infer_dtype}
       624710    0.181    0.000    0.389    0.000 generic.py:7(_check)
        21819    0.155    0.000    0.155    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        10107    0.150    0.000    1.008    0.000 base.py:253(__new__)
```

So we can see almost all time is spend in garbage collection. While I found that there was an issue with this in Python 2.6 I don't think this is now an issue rather then it just needs to clean up a lot because of the loops.

I'm not to much of an expert on Python datatypes, but I was thinking it would maybe be possible to:

create a dict with a set of only the "True" indexes of each dummy column and then instead of having to check which values > 0 and then multiply the columns, I can just take the intersect of the sets and sum these indexes. But this still requires the iterrows() and while(). Also would this be better done on a dataframe or series or numpy arrays?

Comment: I'm guessing whatever you need to do can be accomplished with `DataFrame.groupby`; can you provide some sample data and an example of some simplified `some_groupby_stuff` operation and your expected output?

Comment: `.iterrows()` is notoriously slow. Try to find a way to perform the operations you need using idiomatic/builtin Pandas methods.

Comment: @AMC, the .iterrows() only takes 80ms when not performing the comparison operation so that's not the bottleneck here. However if you know a way to do it without iterating that would be great.

Comment: @ALollz, I'll try to add some data tomorrow, don't have it on this pc

Comment: _However if you know a way to do it without iterating that would be great._ I don't, since I don't know what the goal/operation is.

Comment: @AMC I added all code which can generate data and a function which does all operations.

Comment: @ALollz I added all code which can generate data and a function which does all operations.

Comment: How does `function_to_speed_up()` fit into the rest of the program? There are now multiple pieces of code in there, what does the program actually look like?

Comment: @AMC, sorry renamed test() to function_to_speed_up(), you can just copy-paste all code under  "EDIT:" that's the entire program.